# Error in my Java Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: java, syntax-error, fibonacci

```
public class Arrays {
public static void main(String[] args){
long Fib[] = new long[100];
Fib[0] = 1;
Fib[1] = 1;
int i = 0;
    while(i <= 100){
        Fib[i+2]= Fib[i] + Fib[i+1];
        System.out.println(Fib[i]);
        i++;
    }

}
}
```

I used this to find Fibonacci numbers, but it starts giving me strange readings at around the 94th term. Anyone care to explain? I'm totally new to Java, so please don't hate if it's something obvious.
Here's some snippets of the error'ed output, but everything else looks fine:

```
832040

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100

1346269
```

...

```
63245986

at Arrays.main(102334155
Arrays.java:8)

165580141
```

...

```
4660046610375530309

7540113804746346429

-6246583658587674878

1293530146158671551

-4953053512429003327

-3659523366270331776

-8612576878699335103

6174643828739884737
```

Comment: This is dangerous : `Fib[i+2]= Fib[i] + Fib[i+1];` when `i==98`, as you have declared the array only for `100` elements. Now guess what is wrong ! One way is try declaring an array to hold `103` elements.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution. you are trying to access 102th element  i + 2 where i = 100

```
 Fib[0] = 1;
 Fib[1] = 1;
 int i = 2;
 while(i < 100){
      Fib[i]= Fib[i-1] + Fib[i-2];
      System.out.println(Fib[i]);
      i++;
 }
```

Furthermore, 97th Fibonacci number exceeds `long` range where it is between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. 97th Fibonacci is 83,621,143,489,848,410,000 you should use `BigInteger` instead of `long`

Below code prints until 1000 digit fibonacci number.

```
   BigInteger first = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger second = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger temp;// = new BigInteger("0");
    int counter = 1;

     while(numberOfDigits(second) < 1000)
     {
         temp = new BigInteger(second.toString());
         second = second.add(first);
         first = new BigInteger(temp.toString());
         counter++;
     }
     System.out.print(counter);


}

public static int numberOfDigits(BigInteger number)
{
      return number.toString().length();
}
```

Comment: Moreover `long` is not able to handle such large terms ! Check the results when `i==97` , I may be wrong though.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot yes you are right. `BigInteger` should be used here.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
```

means that the array index 100 does not exist.

```
`long Fib[] = new long[100];`
```

creates indexes 0 - 99

Comment: If the above comment is true about long not being big enough, look into BigInt Objects.  Also, you might be able to use ArrayList<BigInt> instead of long[] and you don't have the problem of running into the index out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` reaches 98, `Fib[i+2]` will evaluate to `Fib[100]`, which will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `Fib` has length 100 and arrays are zero-index (as you demonstrated by assigning `Fib[0]`).

Also, you are getting negative results because the results are too large to fit into a `long`, so they are overflowing. The maximum value of a long is [`9,223,372,036,854,775,807`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and the 93rd Fibonacci number is the first one to exceed this with a value of `12,200,160,415,121,876,738`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need in arrays to generate Fibonacci sequence.
Another trick is to use double (long is too small for 100th Fibonacci number)

```
  double penultimate = 1; // <- long is not long enough ;) use double or BigInteger
  double ultimate = 1;

  System.out.println(penultimate);

  for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
    System.out.println(ultimate);

    double h = penultimate + ultimate;
    penultimate = ultimate;
    ultimate = h;
  }
```

Comment: If a `long` is to small to hold a value I doubt that a `double` will hold that value _exactly_. After all these values are not powers of two.

Comment: Exactly,  `double` can not hold this big data. `double` is 64 bit floating point number while `long` is 64 bit signed integer. They both have 64 bits to store data. Using `BigInteger` is a solution for this obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can iterate loop 98 times to get the series.
It will give you last element of `Fib[100] = 6174643828739884737` .

```
long Fib[] = new long[100];
Fib[0] = 1;
Fib[1] = 1;
int i = 0;
    while(i < 98){
                    Fib[i+2]= Fib[i] + Fib[i+1];
                    System.out.println(Fib[i]);
                    i++;
                }
```